# Using "Or" in Filter

Tags: vba, ms-access, search, filter, subform

I've a search button which when clicked shows the records in sub-form that match the values in text boxes in the parent form. And I have a radio button to choose between "And Search"(if matches all the criteria) and "Or Search"(if matches any one of the criteria). I'm using filter to show the result. This works perfectly  for the "And Search" but not for "Or Search". When during "Or Search" all records despite any value in the text boxes are shown. 
My code is as below.
Hoping to find a solution here. Thank You.

```
    Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim StrId, StrName, FilterId, FilterName, AndOr As String
    Dim IntRadio as Integer

    If Not IsNull(Forms!ParentForm!TxId.Value) Then
        StrId = Forms!ParentForm!TxId.Value
    End If

    FilterId = "[BookID] Like '*" & StrId & "*'"
    FilterName = "[BookName] Like '*" & StrName & "*'"

    If IntRadio = 1 Then
        AndOr = " and "
    Else
        AndOr = " or "
    End If

    Me.Filter = FilterId & AndOr & FilterName 
    Me.FilterOn = True
        Me.Requery

    If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "No Records", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "No Data"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Check what you're getting for `FltrName` --- see what `Debug.Print FltrName` shows you.  Since you're not giving `StrName` a value, I suspect `FltrName` contains this: `[BookName] Like '**'`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The empty string was the problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim StrId, StrName, StrFilter, AndOr As String
Dim IntRadio as Integer

If IntRadio = 1 Then
    AndOr = " and "
Else
    AndOr = " or "
End If

If Not IsNull(Forms!ParentForm!TxId.Value) Then
　　　　StrId = Forms!ParentForm!TxId.Value
　　　　StrFilter = StrFilter & "[BookID] Like '*" & StrId & "*'" & AndOr
End If

If Not IsNull(Forms!ParentForm!TxName.Value) Then
　　　　StrId = Forms!ParentForm!TxName.Value
　　　　StrFilter = StrFilter & "[BookName] Like '*" & StrName & "*'" & AndOr
End If  

StrFilter = Left(StrFilter, Len(StrFilter) - 4)

Me.Filter = StrFilter

Me.FilterOn = True
Me.Requery

If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "No Records", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "No Data"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spelt `filtername` differently on two separate occasions. one with `filter` and one `fltr`. I would change to the following instance, notice I put I and E in.

```
FilterName = "[BookName] Like '*" & StrName & "*'"
```